# Notation for ordered lists with no repetition of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is the notation for a set of $n$ elements (with no repetition) and $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ for an ordered list of $n$ elements (with potential repetition), what is the notation for an ordered list of $n$ elements with **no repetition** of elements?

Comment: Let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be an ordered list of $n$ **pairwise distinct** elements. (That is, just use textual description.)

Comment: @dtldarek The problem with that is that I may have other lists without that restriction that would share the same notation.

Comment: $\{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$ can have repetition: you just have  $\{ a,a \} = \{ a\}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, but it doesn't result in a set of $n$ unique elements. What I want is an ordered list of $n$ unique elements. $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ doesn't give me that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some solutions:**

1. Just use textual description, for example

   > Let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be an ordered list of $n$ **pairwise distinct** elements.

   It doesn't matter that some other lists use the same notation, it's enough to remind the reader sometimes that it was defined this way:

   > Note that we can use property (12.34) because elements of sequence $(a_k)_{k=1}^{n}$ were defined to be pairwise distinct (cf. definition 5.67).
2. Introduce your own notation.

   > In this paper we will use notation $(\!(a_1, \ldots, a_n)\!)$ to say that elements of sequence $(\!(a_k)\!)_{k=1}^{n}$ are pairwise distinct.

   If you are using $\LaTeX$, then often it is nice to define your own command for that.
3. Use a function instead of a sequence, namely observe that a sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ could be defined/manipulated as a function: $f(k) = a_k$. The relevant terms for functions are: *injection*, *injective* and *one-to-one*.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: It does help :) Thank you very much!